# Why do some beers smell like cannabis?

Tags: aroma

In my experience, some beers smell like cannabis. Stella Artios is a distinctive example.

What causes this? - Is it due to a type of hop, or a style?

Answer (score 11):

The fact that both Humulus lupulus (hops) and Cannabis sativa (marijuana) have similar organoleptic properties (taste and smell) could indicate a common ancestry--but it isn't proof. Lots of plants make similar aroma molecules, known as terpenes and terpenoid compounds, including lemons (which make limonene), lavender (linalool) and conifers (pinene) -- but none of them are closely related to cannabis or hops.

[Full article here](http://www.popsci.com/science/article/2012-11/beersci-marijuana-related-hops)

Comment: In which case - why don't more beers smell like cannabis?

Comment: Because most of the aroma is stripped out in the brewing process, unless it's actively pushed back in through dry hopping.

Comment: They do in fact have a common ancestry.  Both are, they are both member of the [Cannabaceae family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannabaceae).

Comment: I think it is kind of like Humans and Apes are both primates. I agree they have that ancestry; but that small percent variability makes a world of difference.

Comment: @Grohlier much closer than that even. Think dogs and wolves, not humans and apes.

Answer (score 7):

The 'dank' scent you're experiencing is the smell of Hops - among the closest botanical neighbors to the Marijuana plant and a key ingredient of beer. The two plants both look and smell nearly identical. Specifically, the dank, resiny scent you pick up from a very hoppy brew is the smell of so-called "Alpha Acids" -  which are chemically a part of the same family as THC, the active ingredient in Marijuana.

As to why some beers are, well, dank, and others aren't? It's a factor of the highly variable alpha acid content in different [hop varietals](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/138/does-the-climate-and-growing-conditions-of-hops-effect-the-taste-of-a-beer-like/145#145), as well as a question of [process](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/127/dry-hopping-versus-regular-hopping). Most of the aromatic alpha acids in hops boil off or dissolve as part of the normal fermentation process, however, some brewers 'dry hop' their beer -  adding additional hops at the end of the process, with the explicit purpose of enhancing the aromatic qualities of the beer.

Comment: actually the plants are close enough that one can be grafted onto the other.